# Weighted difference of observation relative to all other observation in a group (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following sample data. There are three groups X, Y, and Z, and observations 1 to 9 that are divided into these groups. For each observation, I observe variables A and B. So:

```
test <- data.frame(
  id = 1:9,
  group = c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 3), rep("Z", 3)),
  A = seq(from = 0.15, to = 0.55, by = 0.05),
  B = 5:13
)
```

Which gives

```
  id group    A  B
1  1     X 0.15  5
2  2     X 0.20  6
3  3     X 0.25  7
4  4     Y 0.30  8
5  5     Y 0.35  9
6  6     Y 0.40 10
7  7     Z 0.45 11
8  8     Z 0.50 12
9  9     Z 0.55 13
```

What I have been trying to achieve for quite a while is this: For each observation 1 to 9, sum the weighted difference of that observation's value of A relative to the A value of all other observations of that observation's group. So for observations 1 through 4 (as examples), it should look like this:

```
id 1: (0.15 - 0.15) * 5 + (0.15 - 0.20) * 6 + (0.15 - 0.25) * 7 = -1
id 2: (0.20 - 0.15) * 5 + (0.20 - 0.20) * 6 + (0.20 - 0.25) * 7 = -0.1
id 3: (0.25 - 0.15) * 5 + (0.25 - 0.20) * 6 + (0.25 - 0.25) * 7 = 0.8
id 4: (0.30 - 0.30) * 8 + (0.30 - 0.35) * 9 + (0.30 - 0.40) * 10 = -1.45
```

E.g., for observation 3, this translates to words:

step 1: 0.25 is observation 3's value on A, this value is compared to observation 1's value on A (which is 0.15), this difference of 0.10 is weighted by 5 (observation 1's value on B)

step 2: 0.25 (observation 3's value on A) is compared to observation 2's value on A (0.20) and this difference of 0.05 is weighted by 6 (observation 2's value on B)

step 3: 0.25 (observation 3's value on A) is compared to (its own) value on A and this difference of 0 is weighted by 7 (its own value on B) (I see that this step is not necessary given the difference of 0; it is added for completeness).

step 4: sum of steps 1-3

Is there a feasible way of implementing this in R? I have been trying around with `mutate` and `group_by`, but have been unsuccessful so far. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `group_by()` and a little linear algebra:

```r
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(
  id = 1:9,
  group = c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 3), rep("Z", 3)),
  A = seq(from = 0.15, to = 0.55, by = 0.05),
  B = 5:13
)

test %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(res = A*sum(B) - c(A%*%B))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>      id group     A     B    res
#>   <int> <fct> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 X      0.15     5 -1.   
#> 2     2 X      0.2      6 -0.1  
#> 3     3 X      0.25     7  0.800
#> 4     4 Y      0.3      8 -1.45 
#> 5     5 Y      0.35     9 -0.1  
#> 6     6 Y      0.4     10  1.25 
#> 7     7 Z      0.45    11 -1.90 
#> 8     8 Z      0.5     12 -0.1  
#> 9     9 Z      0.55    13  1.70
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `data.table`:

```
> test[, out := colSums(sapply(A, function(x) (x - A) * B)), by = "group"]
> test
   id group    A  B   out
1:  1     X 0.15  5 -1.00
2:  2     X 0.20  6 -0.10
3:  3     X 0.25  7  0.80
4:  4     Y 0.30  8 -1.45
5:  5     Y 0.35  9 -0.10
6:  6     Y 0.40 10  1.25
7:  7     Z 0.45 11 -1.90
8:  8     Z 0.50 12 -0.10
9:  9     Z 0.55 13  1.70
```

What I do is: I apply the custom function `function(x) (x - A) * B)` to each element of column `A`, which gives me a matrix of `(A[i] - A[j]) * B[j]` elements. Then I sum the columns, getting the resulting vector.

Comment: it doesnt look like you are getting the desired output

Comment: Great, that almost does the job. Is there a way to limit your function by group (X, Y, Z in my example)? In your example, the summation is done across all 9 observations, but I would need it be limited within X (observations 1-3), Y (observations 4-6) and Z (observations 7-9). I hope I am specific enough.

Comment: Did not realize OP needed it by group at first. Corrected the answer using `data.table`, as @gfgm provided one with `dplyr` already ;)

Comment: Thanks, this helps!